# Social button not working in Phonegap Android webview

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, twitter

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-url="https://www.mywebsite.com">Tweet</a>
<div class="fb-messengermessageus" 
  messenger_app_id="xxx" 
  page_id="xxx"
  color="white"
  size="large">
</div>
```

I am trying to show Facebook Like, Share and Twitter tweet buttons on my phonegap app.

When running the above codes on my actual device, Facebook related buttons are totally not visible.

Twitter tweet button is visible, but if you press it, there is an error that says 'Refused to display 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?....'

If I try to add the following in my config.xml:

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="http:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="https:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Then pressing tweet button will have no error, but still, nothing shows up.

Why? How to make these buttons open up corresponding apps or external browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Phonegap you can open the in app browser like so:

```
window.open('fb://profile/xxxx', '_blank', 'hidden=yes');
```

Please refer to [This](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) documentation in order to move forwards. You may have to encode all of the parameters you mentioned above in your URL.

Comment: Do you mean I should use my own icon and detect click, then open the share links, instead of using the official plugins?

Comment: Yes that is always how I have done it. The plugins were terrible I can remember pulling my hair out for days! So when I saw this i felt your pain haha